# Нейронные сети и генетический алгоритм

Tags: python, type-error

```
import random
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from deap import base, creator, tools, algorithms
import gym
import algelitism
import tensorflow as tf

class NeuralNetwork:
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, output_size):
        # Инициализация весов
        self.weights_input_hidden = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([input_size, hidden_size]))
        self.weights_hidden_output = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([hidden_size, output_size]))

    def get_total_weights(self):
        # Подсчет общего числа весов в нейросети
        return tf.size(self.weights_input_hidden) + tf.size(self.weights_hidden_output)

    def get_weights(self):
        # Получение общего числа весов в виде строки
        total_weights = self.get_total_weights()
        return f"({total_weights.numpy()} весов)"

    def set_weights(self, new_weights):
        # Установка новых весов для нейросети
        if len(new_weights) == self.get_total_weights():
            start = 0
            end = tf.size(self.weights_input_hidden)
            self.weights_input_hidden.assign(tf.reshape(new_weights[start:end], self.weights_input_hidden.shape))

            start = end
            end = start + tf.size(self.weights_hidden_output)
            self.weights_hidden_output.assign(tf.reshape(new_weights[start:end], self.weights_hidden_output.shape))
        else:
            raise ValueError("Неверное количество весов")

    def forward(self, input_data):
        # Прямое распространение с активациями
        hidden_activations = tf.nn.relu(np.dot(input_data, self.weights_input_hidden) + 1)
        output_activations = tf.nn.softmax(np.dot(hidden_activations, self.weights_hidden_output) + 1)
        return output_activations

    def predict(self, input_data):
        # Получение предсказания от нейросети
        return self.forward(input_data)


nn = NeuralNetwork(4,5,4)

def update_agent_coordinates(action, agent_coordinates):
    # Получение индекса максимального значения в массиве action

    # Применение действия к координатам агента
    if action == 0:
        # Движение вперед: К первому числу прибавляется 1
        agent_coordinates[0] += 1
    elif action == 1:
        # Движение назад: От первого числа отнимается 1
        agent_coordinates[0] -= 1
    elif action == 2:
        # Движение вправо: К второму числу прибавляется 1
        agent_coordinates[1] += 1
    elif action == 3:
        # Движение влево: От второго числа отнимается 1
        agent_coordinates[1] -= 1

    return agent_coordinates
def get_apple_coordinates():
    # Генерация случайных координат яблока в диапазоне от -100 до 100
    apple = np.array([random.randint(-100, 100), random.randint(-100, 100)])
    return apple
def compute_reward(agent_coordinates, apple_coordinates):
    # Пример: расстояние между координатами агента и яблока
    distance = np.sqrt((agent_coordinates[0] - apple_coordinates[0])**2 + (agent_coordinates[1] - apple_coordinates[1])**2)

    # Пример: штраф за дальнее расстояние
    penalty_threshold = 20.0
    penalty = 1.0 if distance > penalty_threshold else 0.0

    # Пример: высокое вознаграждение, уменьшающееся с приближением к яблоку
    high_reward = 10.0
    scaling_factor = 0.1  # Уменьшает вознаграждение с приближением к яблоку

    # Вычисление вознаграждения с учетом штрафа и расстояния
    reward = high_reward - scaling_factor * distance - penalty
    return reward
def get_fitness(individual):
    nn.set_weights(individual)

    max_generations = 500
    goal_reached = False
    total_reward = 0

    for generation in range(max_generations):
        # Получение координат яблока и агента
        apple_coordinates = get_apple_coordinates()  # Ваш код получения координат яблока
        agent_coordinates = np.array([0, 0])  # Начальные координаты агента

        # Получение предсказания от нейросети
        input_data = np.concatenate([apple_coordinates, agent_coordinates])
        action = np.argmax(nn.predict(input_data.reshape(1, -1)))

        # Выполнение действия в среде
        agent_coordinates = update_agent_coordinates(action, agent_coordinates)

        if (agent_coordinates == apple_coordinates).all():
            goal_reached = True

        reward = compute_reward(agent_coordinates, apple_coordinates)

        total_reward += reward

        # Проверка условий остановки
        if goal_reached or generation >= max_generations:
            break

    return total_reward,


LENGTH_CHROM = 4 * 5 + 5 * 4
print(4 * 5 + 5 * 4)
LOW = 1.0
UP = -1.0
ETA = 20

POPULATION_SIZE = 50
P_CROSSOVER = 0.9
P_MUTATION = 0.2
MAX_GENERATIONS = 150
HALL_OF_FAME_SIZE = 2

hof = tools.HallOfFame(HALL_OF_FAME_SIZE)



creator.create("FitnessMax", base.Fitness, weights=(1.0,))
creator.create("Individual", list, fitness=creator.FitnessMax)

toolbox = base.Toolbox()
toolbox.register("randomWeight", random.uniform, -1.0, 1.0)
toolbox.register("individualCreator", tools.initRepeat, creator.Individual, toolbox.randomWeight, LENGTH_CHROM)
toolbox.register("populationCreator", tools.initRepeat, list, toolbox.individualCreator)

population = toolbox.populationCreator(n=POPULATION_SIZE)


toolbox.register("evaluate", get_fitness)
toolbox.register("select", tools.selTournament, tournsize=2)
toolbox.register("mate", tools.cxSimulatedBinaryBounded, low=LOW, up=UP, eta=ETA)
toolbox.register("mutate", tools.mutUniformInt,low=LOW, up=UP, eta=ETA, indpb=1.0/LENGTH_CHROM)

stats = tools.Statistics(lambda ind: ind.fitness.values)
stats.register("max", np.max)
stats.register("avg", np.mean)


population, logbook = algelitism.eaSimpleElitism(population, toolbox,
                                           cxpb=P_CROSSOVER,
                                           mutpb=P_MUTATION,
                                           ngen=MAX_GENERATIONS,
                                           stats=stats,
                                           halloffame=hof,
                                           verbose=True)

max_fitness_values, mean_fitness_values = logbook.select("max", "avg")

best = hof.items[0]
print(best)

plt.plot(max_fitness_values, color="red", label="Минимальная приспособленность")
plt.plot(mean_fitness_values, color="green", label="Средняя приспособленность")
plt.xlabel("Поколение")
plt.ylabel("Приспособленность")
plt.title("Динамика приспособленности в течение поколений")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

выдает ошибку

```
40
gen     nevals  max     avg
0       50      786.659 656.63
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Програмирование\Python\Тестовые файлы пайтон\mygen.py", line 157, in <module>
    population, logbook = algelitism.eaSimpleElitism(population, toolbox,
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Програмирование\Python\Тестовые файлы пайтон\algelitism.py", line 35, in eaSimpleElitism
    offspring = varAnd(offspring, toolbox, cxpb, mutpb)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\blago\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\deap\algorithms.py", line 73, in varAnd
    offspring[i - 1], offspring[i] = toolbox.mate(offspring[i - 1],
                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\blago\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\deap\tools\crossover.py", line 349, in cxSimulatedBinaryBounded
    c1 = min(max(c1, xl), xu)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'complex'
```

Почему выдает ошибку, ведь в коде я не задавал комплексных чисел?

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Где-то там в недрах этой либы видимо корень из отрицательного числа возникает. Почему - надо разбираться.